# Running an angular two page project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am beginner with Angular .I have an angular project with two pages. Every page has  its own  module.When I run "ng serve" it runs the app.module.ts .But I would like to run the other page which module is called "some-page.module.ts". How can I manage to do this ?

Comment: By convention, the app.module.ts *should* be the bootstrapped module. All of the other modules of the application should be imported in the AppModule. Changing the bootstrapping is *not* the correct way to display multiple pages of the application.

Answer (score 1):

In your main.ts file you ll find

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule) which bootstraps the correct module on application start.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, AppModule **should** be the bootstrapped module. You then pull in other modules like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
import { ProductModule } from './products/product.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    ProductModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `declarations` defines the components within the AppModule.

The `imports` defines the other modules that this module uses. Notice the `ProductModule` specified here. That is the module that provides the pages for all of the product features.

For a complete example, check this out: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Final